# Get error when install requirements.txt for Django

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to follow the tutorial on Heroku for Django and get along till I come to `pip install -r requirements.txt`. While there is no problem with loading Django, dj-database and unicorn, loading psycopg2 stucks and get

> Error: pg_config executable not found.

I have read over a few entries in SO like [Getting Started with Python on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636580/getting-started-with-python-on-heroku-pg-config-executable-not-found) and [Can't figure out where Heroku app is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030599/cant-figure-out-where-heroku-app-is-failing-error-pg-config-executable-not-fo). I have followed the answers and proposals there and I installed postgresql again via brew; all without success.

My PATH is

> /usr/local/bin : /usr/bin : /bin : /usr/sbin : /sbin : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-pakages : /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin : /Users/Martin/anaconda/bin : /usr/X11/bin

and my pg_config is where it should be and is added to the PATH.
But I still get the message

> Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
>       or specify the full executable path with the option:
>       python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
>       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

I am on OSSiera 10.12.2.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like postgresql-devel package is missing on your OS.

```
brew install postgresql
```

Should solve the issue.

Comment: @user639774 postgresql  was correctly installed. Thanks,

Comment: but I figured out that I had to add the path to pg_config to PATH. Once I found out where this file was I added it to the PATH and after closing and opening a new Terminal everything worked out. Thanks